# bhyve VM & while loop

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am trying to use the following while loop to achieve the following goals:

1. First command inside the loop is to run the installation one time only.
2. Second command is to run the VM normally without the ISO file.

Can you please show me the right way to achieve that.

Code:

```
# The VM loop

while true; do # Start the installation

    bhyve -Hw -c ${cpu} -m ${ram}G \
      -s 0,hostbridge \
      -s 1,virtio-net,${tap} \
      -s 2,virtio-blk,/dev/zvol/zroot/VMs/${name}/disk0 \
      -s 3,ahci-cd,${FreeBSD_ISO} \
      -s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:${vnc},w=1024,h=768,wait \
      -s 30,xhci,tablet \
      -s 31,lpc \
      -l bootrom,/zroot/VMs/efi.fd \
      ${name}

    exit=$?

    if [ $exit -eq 0 ]; then

        bhyve -Hw -c ${cpu} -m ${ram}G \
          -s 0,hostbridge \
          -s 1,virtio-net,${tap} \
          -s 2,virtio-blk,/dev/zvol/zroot/VMs/${name}/disk0 \
          -s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:${vnc},w=1024,h=768 \
          -s 30,xhci,tablet \
          -s 31,lpc \
          -l bootrom,/zroot/VMs/efi.fd \
          ${name}

    elif [ $exit -ne 0 ]; then

        break;

    fi

done > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

the exit status from `bhyve`.

0 rebooted
1 powered off
2 halted
3 triple fault
4 exited due to an error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: Assuming the script does not work, please describe what actually happens and what you want to happen. Copy&paste the actual output and/or error message and show the expected output if any.

Answer (score 0):

I made it by removing the first command (Installation) from the loop and starting the loop after completion of the Installation command as follows:

```
Installation()
{
bhyve -Hw -c ${cpu} -m ${ram}G \
  -s 0,hostbridge \
  -s 1,virtio-net,${tap} \
  -s 2,virtio-blk,/dev/zvol/zroot/VMs/${name}/disk0 \
  -s 3,ahci-cd,${FreeBSD_ISO} \
  -s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:${vnc},w=1024,h=768,wait \
  -s 30,xhci,tablet \
  -s 31,lpc \
  -l bootrom,/zroot/VMs/efi.fd \
  ${name}
} 
Starting()
{
bhyve -Hw -c ${cpu} -m ${ram}G \
  -s 0,hostbridge \
  -s 1,virtio-net,${tap} \
  -s 2,virtio-blk,/dev/zvol/zroot/VMs/${name}/disk0 \
  -s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:${vnc},w=1024,h=768 \
  -s 30,xhci,tablet \
  -s 31,lpc \
  -l bootrom,/zroot/VMs/efi.fd \
  ${name}
}   
# Start the installation
Installation &&
# Starting the loop after completion of installation
while true; do
  Starting;
  es=$?
  if [ ${es} -ne 0 ]; then
  break;
  fi
done &
```

Comment: What's the actual _question_ that this answers? You don't describe what problem you had that this change fixes either above or here.

Comment: BTW, there are some quoting issues present even in the fixed code -- consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: Hi Charles, I wanted to create a loop for two commands, the first one should run only once. I solved the issue by removing it from the loop and run the loop after the installation is complete.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you extract a question about that, and remove everything that isn't directly relevant to that question? We aren't a collection of scripts, we're a collection of programming questions and their answers.